# R: nested foreach performs worse than non-parallel method?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a nested foreach function spending too much time combining result at the end of each inner loop, and I can also see conbinations stop parallelization (from task monitor). Most surprisingly, it is not even at fast as my non-parallel one append each result to a list (150s vs 30s). My immature idea is to **make the nested foreach combine result only once after all the data are processes**(don't know if it will then suffer from memory overload);or **parallelize the outter loop** instead.

```
merged_slice_R<-foreach (trial = unique(merged_slice$spreadsheet_row),.combine=rbind,.verbose = T)%:%
foreach (id = unique(merged_slice$participant.id),.export=c("timeslice"),.combine=rbind,.verbose = T)%dopar%{
selected<-merged_slice[merged_slice$participant.id==id&
                         merged_slice$spreadsheet_row==trial,]
##align finish time
selected<-rbind(selected, selected[rep(nrow(selected), .maxTime-nrow(selected)), ],make.row.names=F)
selected$timeslice<-as.numeric(rownames(selected))*timeslice-100#fix timestamp after rbind()

return(selected)
}
```

I also tried the default list mode without .combine, it performs even worse. Could anyone help?

last check: it seems foreach automatically combine every 100 results. Then the "combine once only" idea seems impractical.

Comment: Hi, could you provide some data to be able to reproduce your code?

Comment: Combining afterwards and parallelizing only the outer loop are usually good ideas when parallelizing with foreach. Have you tried them?

Comment: @F. Privé Sorry, that is the experiment data that I can't share. The function is just to duplicate the last row of each 'selected' (inner 179, outer 12) to the same length (.Maxtime==1700 rows). I am new to this parallel thing, so I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Just provide some fake data that looks like the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- OK, I myself managed to **parallelize the outer loop**.
- first step is as easy as anyone would intuitively think of,  use `foreach()%dopar%{foreach()%do%{}}`
  structure.
- This will not work unless go with the most importantly step - add `.packages = c("doSNOW")` in the outer
  loop augment, otherwise there will be a `"doSNOW function not found"`
  sort of error.
- Then free to enjoy the efficiency of the real parallel with each core doing one line of works, instead of having all cores waiting for combinations of every 100 results and also of each inner loops.